# Passing function two levels deep not working

Tags: flutter

I have a function on the Grandparent. I pass it down to the parent, and the parent passes it down to the child. The function is called on the child. The expected behaviour is that the function on the grandparent is executed, but it is not. Nothing happens. For testing purposes I also included a button on the parent, that works correctly as expected.

So, what should happen is: when the listTile on the child is tapped, 'print from parent' should appear on the console.

Grandparent (snippet):

```
StateLoaded(
   vm: vm,
   procesStatus: _procesStatus,
   onTapChange: () => print('print from parent'),
),
```

Parent (snippet):

```
class StateLoaded extends StatelessWidget {
  const StateLoaded({
    @required this.vm,
    @required ProcesStatus procesStatus,
    @required this.onTapChange,
  }) : _procesStatus = procesStatus;

  final AuthViewModel vm;
  final ProcesStatus _procesStatus;
  final Function() onTapChange;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Visibility(
      visible: vm.failureVm.failure == null &&
          vm.isAuth &&
          _procesStatus == ProcesStatus.loaded,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 8),
          Avatar(),
          Divider(),
          UserName(vm: vm, onTapChange: onTapChange),
```

Child:

```
class UserName extends StatelessWidget {
  const UserName({
    @required this.vm,
    @required this.onTapChange,
  });

  final AuthViewModel vm;
  final Function() onTapChange;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(
        SimpleLineIcons.pencil,
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        size: 18,
      ),
      title: Text(
        vm.userName ?? '',
        style: linkTextStyle,
      ),
      onTap: onTapChange(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onTap, on ListTile child, is wrong.

There's 2 ways to correct it :

```
onTap: onTapChange,
```

or

```
  onTap: () => onTapChange(),
```

Comment: Wow, I struggled with this for hours. Thanks for your quick answer. Both ways work indeed.